# Quartz.Net Cron Expression for Trigger

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am trying execute a script every weekday at 6:00 pm. (0 0 18 ? * MON-FRI *)
Also, I am on Sundays this script should run at 4:00 pm. (0 0 16 ? * SUN *)

I am using Quartz.Net
I was curious if it is possible to combine the two as one cron expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot combine them - use 2 triggers mapped to the same job for that.

Using Cron expression you define intervals between events (jobs in this context) like

> "run every X *hours/minutes/seconds* etc on *each day/the following
>   days*"

and so on.

And your Sunday's condition doesn't have any common criteria with you weekday schedule.